# jQuery youtubin plugin only working with a selector

Tags: jquery, plugins, ssl, https, youtube

I'm using [youtubin](http://jonraasch.com/blog/youtubin-jquery-plugin) to embed youtube videos on a secure page.  It works whenever I specify a jQuery selector:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#foo a').youtubin();
});
</script>

<div id="foo">
  <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/kUini08olkQ&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1">YouTube Video</a>
</div>
```

It doesn't work when I just call youtubin:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $.youtubin();
});
</script>

<div id="foo">
  <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/kUini08olkQ&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1">YouTube Video</a>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery 1.3.2, swfobject 2.2, and youtubin 1.2.  Any thoughts on why it only works with a selector?  Thanks

Comment: The point would be, where the heck should youtubin() attach the behaviour to if not to a html element?

Comment: @Yves M: the linked page specifically demonstrates the code (`$.youtubin();`) that the OP is asking about.

Comment: are you getting any sort of error when you call `$.youtubin();`? Are you sure there are youtube links on the page when you do so? It's hard to figure out what's wrong with as little info as you've provided.

Comment: @Bears: No errors...firebug doesn't say anything.  I'm sure there are youtube links on the page.  The code I provided above is from my test page and includes a youtube link.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the format of the URL of the Youtube video. Example:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_c6HsiixFS8">Click here</a>
```